# How to handle Kafka DLT properly?

Tags: apache-kafka, event-handling, spring-kafka, event-driven, kafka-dlt

Let's assume we have a kafka topic with N partitions for product related events, partitioned by product id.

I think the standard approach to messages that we currently cannot process (due to some errors such as availability of internal/external services) is to send them to a DLT - dead letter topic.

I would like to know what the best practice is and so I have a couple questions:

1. Is it a correct approach to create a DLT per each consumer group of such topic?
2. Is it correct to resend them back from this DLT topic to the main topic in order to retry them?

What I am thinking is that applying business logic to such events from DLT will result in possible concurrent event execution for the same key (one from DLT and one from the main topic). On the other hand, what if we do not have permissions to write to the main topic?

The only approach in this scenario that I see is that we need a third topic (internal topic, one per consumer group of the main topic), and handle events in the following way:

- Events from main topic are moved to internal topic (this can never
  fail).
- Events from internal topic are processed with business logic, if
  processing fails we move them to the DLT topic.
- Events from DLT topic are moved back to the internal topic at some
  regular intervals.

But this approach requires a lot of resources (topics, partitions), on the other hand if we just consume events from DLT it is getting really messy with the concurrency issues. I would like to know the best practice for this kind of scenario.

Comment: There is no "one size fits all" answer; you have to decide what to do based on your particular requirements.